# Jetty 9.4.14 ProxyServlet increase or disable timeout

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am using a embedded jetty (9.4.14.v20181114) for implementing the following setup

[image: JettySetup].

As shown in the picture all clients are accessing the proxy server and based on some business rules the proxy forwards to one of the web servers
using jetty's `ProxyServlet#rewriteTarget` method. To to this I define new a class which extends ProxyServlet and overrides `rewriteTarget`

Each server from the picture is deployed on different machine.

Some client requests took time to be processed and it turns out that if a request needs more than 30 seconds the proxy responds to the client with

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout
Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2019 09:04:37 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json"
```

Is there a way to increase this timeout or to completely remove it.

I have tried the following 2 things but neither of them worked

1. Set idleTimeout of the ServerConnector

```
Server server = new Server();
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
connector.setHost(ip);
connector.setPort(port);
connector.setIdleTimeout(45000);
server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });
```

2. During the overriding of `rewriteTarget` I set a `this.setTimeout(45000);`

```
public class RoutingServlet extends ProxyServlet {
   ...
    @Override
    protected String rewriteTarget(HttpServletRequest request) {
               this.setTimeout(45000);

               // ... business logic based on request body and headers ...

               return rewrittenUrl;
        }   
   ...
}
```

Both approaches do not have any effect of the situation and after the 30th second the proxy responds to the client with `HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout` while the Web server which actually handles the request is still processing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 idle timeouts to worry about, but ultimately it sounds like the error you are getting is from the proxy based client ([due to the 504 Gateway Timeout response](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-proxy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AbstractProxyServlet.java#L637-L650)).

But before we go there, ensure that your `ServerConnector` has a sane Idle Timeout set (should probably be a value higher then your proxy client).  This controls the connection idle timeout between your "Client" and "ProxyServer" (per your diagram)

Next, if you are using something like `AsyncProxyServlet`, just set the `"idleTimeout"` init-parameter ([which defaults to `"30000"` if unspecified](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.14.v20181114/jetty-proxy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AbstractProxyServlet.java#L311-L314)).  This controls the idle timeout between your "ProxyServer" and "Jetty Server" (per your diagram)

Eg:

```java
    Server server = new Server();

    HttpConfiguration http_config = new HttpConfiguration();
    http_config.setSendServerVersion(true);
    http_config.setSendDateHeader(false);

    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(http_config));
    http.setPort(8080);
    http.setIdleTimeout(45000);
    server.addConnector(http);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    context.setContextPath("/");

    ServletHolder proxyHolder = new ServletHolder("proxy", AsyncProxyServlet.class);
    proxyHolder.setInitParameter("idleTimeout", "44000");
    context.addServlet(proxyHolder, "/proxy");

    ServletHolder defHolder = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
    context.addServlet(defHolder, "/");

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.addHandler(context);
    handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());

    server.setHandler(handlers);
    server.start();
    server.join(); // wait for server thread to finish
```

Alternatively, you can do it in your custom `AsyncProxyServlet` too.

```java
package jetty.proxy;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;
import org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.AsyncProxyServlet;

public class MyProxyServlet extends AsyncProxyServlet
{
    @Override
    protected HttpClient createHttpClient() throws ServletException {
        HttpClient client = super.createHttpClient();
        client.setIdleTimeout(44000);
        return client;
    }
}
```

Comment: Overriding the `AsyncProxyServlet#createHttpClient` works. As you recommend I also set `setIdleTimeout` to the `ServerConnector` instance. Now now the proxy behaves as expected. Thank you!
  
Can you, please, also clarify how these two timeouts are related? In my current situation the system behaves in the same way if I override the http proxy client but don't set idle timeout of the connector.

Comment: I also had to set a generic 'timeout' init parameter, like: `proxyHolder.setInitParameter("timeout", "44000"); `